# Remove whitespace at end of sentence

Tags: go

Here's some context.

The user enters `test hello world`                   (including the empty whitespace)

I need this input to be changed into `test hello world`

Heres some code, if I enter the previous string with the whitespace, it only removes 1 space and adding more than one to the trimsuffix will create singular use cases such as only 10 spaces.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    text := scanner.Text() 
    text = strings.TrimSuffix(text, " ")
    fmt.Printf("%s", text)

}
```

Comment: Yes it does! thanks for the help, maybe I'm just terrible at using stack!

Just for anyone reading `text = strings.TrimSpace(text)`

And heres some documentation 

TrimSpace returns a slice of the string s, with all leading and trailing white space removed, as defined by Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text = strings.Trim(text, " ")` to remove spaces on both sides.

If you only need at the end, then use `text = strings.TrimRight(text, " ")`